# How to best backup AWS-hosted systems?

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are deploying a number of servers at AWS and need to work-out a general-purpose backup strategy. The requirements are:

1. Retain the ability to recover full systems or individual files or subdirectories going back up to N weeks (with N varying per system).
2. Be able to exclude certain sub-trees (or mount-points).
3. Store the backups on S3 (or even Glacier).
4. Minimize costs and times -- use *incremental* backups to avoid storing too many copies of unchanged files.

EC2 snapshots seems like an obvious solution, but recovering individual files while the originating system is still running is, apparently, not always possible (the dreadful ["Marketplace product code" error message](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html)). Also, it is only possible to dump the entire filesystem (volume) -- without a way to exclude anything.

That leaves the "traditional" options of [Amanda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amanda/) and [Duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/), which nowadays both have S3 as the storage option.

Am I right with my assessment of limitations of the EC2 snapshots? Any comments comparing usage of Amanda vs. Duplicity at AWS? Thank you!

Comment: You probably ought to think about whether or not you really want backups of your AWS infrastructure to be stored in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

For full system backups in EC2, you should go with EBS Snapshots. For data backup in S3/Glacier I would go with [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) in Linux systems and [Cloudberry Backup](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/amazon-s3-cloud-desktop-backup.aspx) tools in Windows (Not free, but worths each dollar).

S3cmd is a simple command line tool you can use in your standard backup scripts to push a copy into a S3 bucket. For Glacier rotations, use S3 lifecycle rules. Works like a charm.

In Windows, I have not been able to find a decent free backup tool for S3, but Cloudberry is just great. It allows you to configure hundreds of options (Versioning, file exclusions, multiple storage backends...). Also, no issue with it up to date.

Bonus Track: For SQL Server specific S3 backups, I would use the [Keymetric SQL Backup Master](http://www.sqlbackupmaster.com) solution instead of Cloudberry's one. It's simpler, effective and cheap.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you are really trusting Amazon with your data.

Comment: Is your strategy capable of meeting the requirements I listed? We aren't using Windows here, but any plan for backing up MySQL databases may be of interest.

Comment: IMHO, S3cmd sync command + --exclude parameters for subtree exclusion + S3 bucket versioning should give you the functionality you intend to achieve.

Comment: @Jacob, I understood from the question that the objective was S3 backed backups.

Comment: The backups shall end up stored on S3, correct. But which tool would create them -- "ec2 create-snapshot" or something else -- is my question...

Comment: EC2 Snapshots storage backend is Amazon S3 by nature, but these snapshots are not available to download through the S3 interface, but only to be used in the EC2 snapshot interface. If what you mean is to set that snapshot available for download you should better go for EC2 Export API. All of my indications in the Answer are for raw data backups, not system-wide machine image cloning. If you require a higher level of replication for your snapshots you can use the EBS copy snapshot API to create a snapshot replica in another AWS region.

Comment: No, I do not need much replication of the backups. What I do need is what I listed in my question -- the four items. Thanks!